# How to display multiline items in Common Lisp LTK listbox?

Tags: listbox, common-lisp, tk-toolkit

With the below code, I can create a listbox:

```lisp
(ltk:with-ltk ()
  (let ((listbox (make-instance 'ltk:listbox)))
    (ltk:listbox-append listbox
                        (list (format nil "This~%is~%some~%multiline~%text.")))
    (ltk:pack listbox)))
```

However, the text gets displayed on a single line with `\n` instead of the expected multiline text. What should I do to display the text on multiple lines?

I tried using a `ltk:text` as below, but instead of displaying the text contents, it instead displayed the print representation of the `ltk:text` object itself!

```lisp
(ltk:with-ltk ()
  (let ((listbox (make-instance 'ltk:listbox)))
    (ltk:listbox-append
     listbox
     (list (let ((text (make-instance 'ltk:text)))
             (setf (ltk:text text)
                   (format nil "This~%is~%a~%multiline~%text."))
             text)))
    (ltk:pack listbox)))
```